# Decompress a single file from a zip folder without writing in disk

Tags: scala, zip, compression

Is it possible to decompress a single file from a zip folder and return the decompressed file without storing the data on the server?

I have a zip file with an unknown structure and I would like to develop a service that will serve the content of a given file on demand without decompressing the whole zip and also without writing on disk.
So, if I have a zip file like this

```
zip_folder.zip
  |  folder1
       |  file1.txt
       |  file2.png
  |  folder 2
       |  file3.jpg
       |  file4.pdf
  |  ...
```

So, I would like my service to receive the name and path of the file so I could send the file.

For example, `fileName` could be `folder1/file1.txt`

```scala
 def getFileContent(fileName: String): IBinaryContent = {
    val content: IBinaryContent = getBinaryContent(...)

    val zipInputStream: ZipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(content.getInputStream)
    val outputStream: FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)

    var zipEntry: ZipEntry = null
    var founded: Boolean = false
    while ({
      zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry
      Option(zipEntry).isDefined && !founded
    }) {

      if (zipEntry.getName.equals(fileName)) {

        val buffer: Array[Byte] = Array.ofDim(9000) // FIXME how to get the dimension of the array
        var length = 0

        while ({
          length = zipInputStream.read(buffer)
          length != -1
        }) {
          outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }
        outputStream.close()
        founded = true
      }
    }

    zipInputStream.close()
    outputStream /* how can I return the value? */

  }
```

How can I do it without writing the content in the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of the `FileOutputStream` to uncompress the zip entry into memory. Then call `toByteArray()` on it.

---

Also note that, technically, you would not even need to decompress the zip part if you can transmit it over a protocol (think: HTTP(S)) which supports the deflate encoding for its transport (which is usually the standard compression used in Zip files).

Answer (score 0):

So, basically I did the same thing that @cbley recommended. I returned an array of bytes and defined the `content-type` so that the browser can do the magic!

```
def getFileContent(fileName: String): IBinaryContent = {
    val content: IBinaryContent = getBinaryContent(...)

    val zipInputStream: ZipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(content.getInputStream)
    val outputStream: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    var zipEntry: ZipEntry = null
    var founded: Boolean = false
    while ({
      zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry
      Option(zipEntry).isDefined && !founded
    }) {

      if (zipEntry.getName.equals(fileName)) {

        val buffer: Array[Byte] = Array.ofDim(zipEntry.getSize)
        var length = 0

        while ({
          length = zipInputStream.read(buffer)
          length != -1
        }) {
          outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }
        outputStream.close()
        founded = true
      }
    }

    zipInputStream.close()
    outputStream.toByteArray

  }

// in my rest service
@GET
@Path("/content/${fileName}")
def content(@PathVariable fileName): Response = {
    val content = getFileContent(fileName)
    Response.ok(content)
        .header("Content-type", new Tika().detect(fileName)) // I'm using Tika but it's possible to use other libraries
        .build()
}
```